# How to call MS SQL stored procedures with more than one output parameters using Hibernate 4?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Colleagues, could you help me with calling MS SQL 2008 store procedure with two input and two output parameters using Hibernate 4?
The stored procedure looks like:

```
PROCEDURE Product_Create(
        @Return  int  output,
        @ProdID numeric(18,0)  output,

        @PassID numeric(18,0),
        @Amount numeric(18,2))
```

I am trying to use session.createSQLQuery method to call procedure:

```
Query qr = session.createSQLQuery("{? = Product_Create (:PassID, :Amount")});
qr.setParameter("PassID", new BigInteger("999999999"));
qr.setParameter("Amount", new BigDecimal("87384738"));
```

But there are some unclear moments:

1. How to register more than one output parameters?
2. Is session.createSQLQuery approach suitable to call stored procedures with more than one output parameter?

**Update**

I have a MS SQL procedure

```
PROCEDURE Product_Create(
        @Return  int  output,
        @ProdID numeric(18,0)  output,

        @IN$PassID numeric(18,0),
        @IN$Amount numeric(18,2))
```

and have mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <sql-query name="Product_Create" callable="true">
        <return-scalar column = "Return" type="int"/>
        <return-scalar column = "ProdID" type="long"/>
        <![CDATA[CALL IProduct_Create (:@IN$PassID, :@IN$Amount)]]>
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When i run application than i receive exception:

> WARN : [Tue-06 10:11:39,374] jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error:
>   102, SQLState: S0001 ERROR: [Tue-06 10:11:39,374]
>   jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Incorrect syntax near '@P0'. Exception
>   in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could
>   not extract ResultSet     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:130)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:76)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1873)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect
>   syntax near '@P0'.    at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:332)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.dialect.AbstractTransactSQLDialect.getResultSet(AbstractTransactSQLDialect.java:226)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect.getResultSet(SQLServerDialect.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:121)
>     ... 16 more

I tried to make some changes in

```
  <![CDATA[CALL IProduct_Create (:@IN$PassID, :@IN$Amount)]]>
```

but without success.

What is wrong in my mapping?

**UPDATE 1**

Added brackets {} to call procedures. It works when call looks like

```
 <![CDATA[{CALL Product_Create (:@IN$PassID, :@IN$Amount)}]]>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call it with `getNamedQuery()`.

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("product_create")
    .setParameter("PassID", new BigInteger("999999999"))
    .setParameter("Amount", new BigDecimal("87384738"));

List result = query.list();  // here you have DTO List i.e. List<Product>
```

Comment: Jordi Castilla, thank you for your response. Do i need to create mapping file?

Comment: yes, mapping file or java annotated class... you must tell hibernate which table corresponds returned object

Comment: But I have not table which corresponds with returned object with output procedures parameters (@Return and @ProdID). Procedure just returns two parameters (it is not a table or cursor)

Comment: so create a mapping file for view with corresponding values